# Hangs On or After fsck from util-linux 2.20.1

Tags: 12.04, boot, kernel, fsck

I have a box running at DigitalOcean with Ubuntu 12.04

It's rare that my system will boot or takes forever - normally it just hangs / chokes. A reboot from a remote shell used to be pretty quick and I could reconnect within 10 seconds or so. Here's screens shots of where it gets to:

[Hang Image Compilation](http://puu.sh/a38qt/7626e688b8.png)

I have been told that such may happen after a kernel upgrade if their "hypervisor" doesn't have that kernel and that it may require manual setting from DO's support.

I had them mount their ArchLinux recovery disk and checked out the system's /lib/modules: 
I've been told these are the supported kernels that Ubuntu can run with.

[Directory /lib/modules](http://puu.sh/a37ZQ/7960ee4272.png)

I set my kernel to:
ubuntu 12.04 x64 vmlinux-3.8.0-42-generic
From DO's droplet settings.

I'm still getting the above hangs and some of the images above were after such.

Comment: I am wondering, why the DOROOT clean, shows a diff number of files and/or blocks on the partition every-time. Just to be sure, I would do a `fsck` from the recovery mode on the root partition to make sure its fs is in consistent state.